# Is this a logical error in the conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My expected output:

- Only show the `textfield` `colors` when the `button` `add color` is cliked.
- Only one textfield shows when clicking the `button` `add color` is clicked initially then adding more textfields in the next clicked and also be able to remove a specific color.

What is currently happening and my problem:

- When the page initially renders, the `remove` button is shown. In which, it should not be. It must only be shown when a textfield `color` appears.
- Clicking the button `add color` does make the textfield `color` appear. However, instead of just one `textfield`, it displays 2 `textfields`.
- Also, if I remove all of the `textfield` I added, the `Add color` `button` disappears, hence, removing all of the textfields does not allow me to add more of it. In which it should not. Even removing all of the `textfields`, I should still be able to add more colors.

How would I fix this? Am I doing something wrong with the conditionals for the buttons? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**The codes:**

```
const [addColor, setAddColor] = useState(false);
const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);

 //for the colors
  const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setColorList((prevState) => {
      const list = [...prevState];
      list[index][name] = name === "colorStocks" ? +value : value;
      return list;
    });
  };

  const handleColorRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...colorList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setColorList(list);
  };

  const handleColorAdd = () => {
    setAddColor(true);
    setColorList([...colorList, { color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);
  };




  {colorList.map((singleColor, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                        <>
                          {addColor === true && (
                            <>
                              <Grid
                                item
                                xs={6}
                                style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
                              >
                                <TextField
                                  label="Color"
                                  name="color"
                                  type="text"
                                  id="color"
                                  required
                                  value={singleColor.color}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                                />
                              </Grid>
                              <br />
                              <Grid
                                item
                                xs={6}
                                style={{ display: "inline-block" }}
                              >
                                <TextField
                                  label="Stocks"
                                  name="colorStocks"
                                  type="number"
                                  id="colorStocks"
                                  required
                                  value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                                />
                              </Grid>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </>
                      </div>
                      <br />
                      <Grid item xs>
                        {colorList.length >= 1 && (
                          <Button
                            color="secondary"
                            onClick={() => handleColorRemove(index)}
                          >
                            Remove
                          </Button>
                        )}
                      </Grid>
                      <br />

                      {colorList.length - 1 === index && (
                        <Button
                          onClick={handleColorAdd}
                          variant="outlined"
                          color="primary"
                          fullWidth
                        >
                          Add Color
                        </Button>
                      )}

                      {(colorList.length, "- colorList")}
                      <br />
                      {(index, "-index")}
                    </div>
                  ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple issues in your code:

> When the page initially renders, the remove button is shown. In which,
> it should not be. It must only be shown when a textfield color
> appears.

colorList when you initiate your component is equal to:

```
[{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]
```

which length === 1 (one object with two keys and two empty string values)

so the condition:

```
colorList.length >= 1
```

will be true at initial render. Initiate with an empty array rather:

```
const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([]);
```

> Clicking the button addcolor does make the textfield color appear.
> However, instead of just one textfield, it displays 2 textfields.

Your function handleColorAdd changes addColor to true which is good to show the component. However same issue as before: Your original array already has an empty color and you add a second one on top of it, which makes two objects in your colorList:

```
setColorList([...colorList, { color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);
```

Once again, starting with an empty array will resolve this issue.

> Also, if I remove all of the textfield I added, the Add color button
> disappears, hence, removing all of the textfields does not allow me to
> add more of it. In which it should not. Even removing all of the
> textfields, I should still be able to add more colors.

Your `addColor` button is part of the `map` on ColorList. Indeed if colorList becomes an empty array nothing will display anymore. Best solution is to take out the addColor button from this `map` function.